# AngularJS Login

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication

I am trying to make a login for my website. Everything is working and I am currently logged in. Everytime I refresh the page the username and password will dissappear so my login will also dissappear. I do not want that to happen. So what can I do to keep the data in the scopes after a refresh? I get from my php a username password and a permission back and i set the loggedIn to true for my ng-show.

## loginController.js

```
app.controller('loginController', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
$scope.info = {
    uname :'',
    pass : ''
};
$scope.loggedIn = false;
$scope.name ={};
$scope.pass = {};

$scope.logout = function(loggedIn){
   loggedIn=false;
};

$scope.users={};


$scope.logThatShitIn = function(info, name){ 
    $http.post("php/userData.php",info)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.name = data.user;
            $scope.pass = data.pass;
            $scope.loggedIn = 'true';
        }
    );        
};
}]);
```

## index.html -> my header

```
    <body ng-controller='loginController'>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headerName left">
            <div class="headerNameText lname right">
                lname
            </div>

            <div class="headerNameText fname right">
                fname
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav left">
            <ul>
                <li class="navText">
                    <a ui-sref="dishes">Dishes</a>
                </li>

                <li class="navText">
                    <a ui-sref="addRecipe" ng-show='loggedIn'>Add Recipe</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="loginHeader right">
            <div class="loginButton" ng-hide='loggedIn'>
                <a ui-sref="login">log in</a>
            </div>

            <div class="logoutButton custFont" ng-show='loggedIn'>
                <a href='#' ng-click='loggedIn = false'>log out</a>
            </div>

            <div class="loggedIn" ng-show='loggedIn'>
                <p>welcome {{name}} !!</p>
            </div>

        </div>
```

## login.html

```
<div>
<form name="login" ng-submit="logThatShitIn(info)">
    <label>Username</label><br/>
    <input type=text ng-model="info.uname" placeholder="Username"><br/><br/>
    <label>Password</label><br/>
    <input type="password" ng-model="info.pass" placeholder="Password"><br/><br/>
    <input type='submit' value="Log in!"/>
</form>

<div ng-show='loggedIn'>
    {{name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you storing the login details in your client and re-sending them on every page request? Why aren't you using sessions? And instead of setting `loggedIn` within your client, do it server-side in the session so it will persist across page requests.

Comment: @BenFortune Thanks for answering my code. I havent tried this yet. I am still trying the method of the cookiestore first. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to remain logged in after refreshing the page you will have to store their information on the client.

Try using `$cookieStore` to store their username and password in your log in function:

```
$cookieStore.put('username', name);
$cookieStore.put('password', pass);
```

Then you can retrieve the credentials and log in on a refresh in your `app.run` block. Put your login function into a `loginService` and inject it in app.run.

```
app.run(['loginService', function(loginService){
    var username = $cookieStore.get('username');
    var password = $cookieStore.get('password');
    loginService.login(username, password);
}]);
```

[documentation on $cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookieStore)

Comment: Hey @Nick, thanks for answering my question. I've looked up the cookie store and it is working fine now. The only thing is that i have to refresh the page to see if someone is actually loggedin. Is there a way to let the page refresh it self? it looks like ng-show doesnt work that well in my code. Did i do something wrong?